# Perform partial one list items match into another with a catch

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two list :

```
list_1 = ['world', 'abc', 'bcd', 'ghy', 'car', 'hell', 'rock']
list_2 = ['the world is big', 'i want a car', 'puppies are best', 'you rock the world']
```

I would like to check if words of list_1 exists in list_2 in any shape or form and simple delete that whole sentence from list_2 and finally, print list_2

For example:

```
the word 'world' from list_1 should take out the sentence 'the world is big' from list_2
the word 'car' from list_2 should take out the sentence 'i want a car'
```

I have tried using list comprehension like this, but it sadly repeats

```
output = [j for i in list_1 for j in list_2 if i not in j]
```

Comment: you could use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider giving meaningfull names to your variable when you can, this helps you writing your code

What you want is

- iterate over the sentences
- for each check that no word from `list_1` is in it

```
output = [sentence for sentence in list_2
          if all(word not in sentence for word in list_1)]

print(output)  # ['puppies are best']
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a separate list comprehension in the condition expression. In your comprehension you're adding a `j` `for i in list_1` for every `i` that is not in `j`, which is why you're getting repeats.

```py
output = [j for j in list_2 if all([i not in j for i in list_1])]
```

Comment: @PanDe Careful that solution shows a list comprehension in the `all()` ,that is less performant than the full generator solution you can see in my answer Because it first builds and stores the list in memory then iterate again on it, whereas the full generator just iterates once

Answer (score 2):

You want to check if any word appears in a phrase, so `any` is the way to go. In my opinion this is more readable than using `all` and negating the check.

```
words = ['world', 'abc', 'bcd', 'ghy', 'car', 'hell', 'rock']
phrases = ['the world is big', 'i want a car', 'puppies are best', 'you rock the world']

result = [phrase for phrase in phrases if not any(word in phrase for word in words)]
print(result)
```

You get `['puppies are best']`.

---

The solution is roughly equivalent to this:

```
result = []
for phrase in phrases:
    contains_any_word = False
    for word in words:
        if word in phrase:
            contains_any_word = True
            break
    if not contains_any_word:
        result.append(phrase)
```

Comment: You could use the `for/break` statement to avoid having a temp variable https://repl.it/@azro352/SadSalmonMachinecodeinstruction#main.py ;)

Comment: I aalways can't remember what the `else` means in this context. I would have loved a new keyword like `nobreak`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `set` intersection?

```
list_1 = ['world', 'abc', 'bcd', 'ghy', 'car', 'hell', 'rock']
list_2 = ['the world is big', 'i want a car', 'puppies are best', 'you rock the world']

words = set(list_1)
output = [i for i in list_2 if not words & set(i.split())]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['puppies are best']
```